# How can I read multiple lines of user input from the console?

Tags: c#, windows, input, console

I want to read multiple lines of user input from the console, but also allow termination of input with an escape sequence like CTRL-C. My problem is canceling the last call to ReadLine() when the escape sequence is pressed. I've tried multithreading and forcing the thread to close, but my problem is getting the last line of user input. When the escape sequence is pressed, the last line is lost and I can't get it back using ReadLine() from the main thread. If I input something like this:

```
Input
Input2 [CTRL-C],
```

I only get 'Input\n'. Is there a way to get multiple lines of input, but capture the last line when the escape sequence is pressed?

Comment: Have you defined a [console control handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for CTRL+C?  Otherwise, the default handler will be executed, calling ExitProcess().

Comment: I did. Also, I'm not set on using Ctrl+C, any escape sequence will work.

Comment: I suppose you could use a loop with KeyAvailable and ReadKey within your CTRL+C handler to grab whatever hasn't yet been read.  ReadLine won't work because the user will never get a chance to end the line...  Or you could try something really funky like taking over standard input from within the CTRL+C handler and writing a line ending to it.  (I haven't tried this and have no idea if it would work.)

Comment: I tried using a KeyAvailable/ReadKey loop and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cool; I was just guessing without any coding, but if it works I'll add the above suggestion as an actual answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in my comment above, it apparently works to:

- set a [console control handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for CTRL+C and
- handle the CTRL-C by looping through the remaining input using Console.KeyAvailable and Console.ReadKey.